# DB not changing when testing Flask-Security with peewe and PyTest

Tags: testing, flask, peewee, flask-security

I just got into testing my flask application with pytest, and it mostly works as expected. Unfortunately the test uses the live DB instead a mock one. I'm quite sure this has to do with the fact, that flask-security is using peewee's database_wrapper instead of an "straightforward" database.

Here's some code. This is from the test:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
db_fd, belavoco_server.app.config['DATABASE']  = {  'name': 'userLogin_TEST.db',
                                                    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase' }                                                   }

belavoco_server.app.config['TESTING'] = True
client = belavoco_server.app.test_client()

#this seems not to help at all
with belavoco_server.app.app_context():
     belavoco_server.users.user_managment.db_wrapper.init_app(belavoco_server.app)

yield client

os.close(db_fd)
os.unlink(belavoco_server.app.config['DATABASE'])
```

This is some code from my bv_user_model.py

```
app.config['DATABASE'] = {
    'name': 'userLogin.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}

app.config['SECURITY_URL_PREFIX'] = "/users"

# Create a database instance that will manage the connection and
# execute queries
db_wrapper = FlaskDB(app)

class Role(db_wrapper.Model, RoleMixin):
    name = CharField(unique=True, default="standard")
    description = TextField(null=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

When preforming the test, Flask is using the `userLogin.db` instead of `userLogin_TEST.db`. I suppose this is because of the db_wrapper in `bv_user_model.py` - but I did not find a way to change this behaviour. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible and that may be the reason why this question has not received enough attention. The fixture appears to be malformatted (no indent). And what is `belavoco_server`? Also, may I ask what is the purpose of unpacking the dictionary keys into `db_fd and belavoco_server.app.config['DATABASE']`? It does not make any sense to me as `db_df` would be a string, not a file descriptor.

Comment: You are right, the question was not well asked, but  I really got lost with this problem, because the code itself worked and I am new to tests. `belavoco_server` is the name of the whole project, the app is created therein. You're right, the unpacking makes no sense, it comes from the code before, which was creating a temporary file with `tempfile.mkstemp()` which returns a pair.

Comment: I did find a solution after all, using the same BaseModel and initializing the database with a temporary file as I did for other tests. Because the example of flask-security used a database wrapper I thought I had to use FlaskDB. Without it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue seems to be this in bv_user_model:

```
app.config['DATABASE'] = {
    'name': 'userLogin.db',
    'engine': 'peewee.SqliteDatabase',
}
```

Since you are using `FlaskDB` with the app that has the production credentials, it seems like the db_wrapper will "remember" that and not be overridden by your tests.

The most straightforward answer would be to not use your app to create the FlaskDB instance directly

```
db = FlaskDB()
```

And then later on initialize it on your app

```
from models import db
def create_app():
    app = ...
    app.config["DATABASE"] = ...
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app
```

Which would let you have a separate function like this which you can use for testing.

```
def create_test_app():
    app = ...
    app.config["DATABASE"] = ...test credentials...
    db.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app
```

and when you create your models, use the FlaskDB instance just the same as you were already.

```
db = FlaskDB()
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, you nailed the problem. I found a solution myself, in the meantime, by ditching FlaskDB and returning to a BaseModel and initiation with `database.init(database_name)` if `not app.config['TESTING']`. This is what worked for all the other tests, but (as I'm explaining in a comment above) I was thinking I had to use a db_wrapper to use flask-security.

Comment: I have never opend and closed connections manually with peewee and Flask. Apparently FlaskDB does this for you. I have used Flask an peewee for a while and never had any problem with not closing connections, I was always assuming they were closed automatically. When using the Models obviously a connection is opend. Should I use a hook to close it when a request ends?